# Event after DataGrid new DataContext

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

in my WPF Window I have `DataGrid`.
`DataGrid` loads data from DataTable like:

```
gridData.DataContext = dataTable
```

All works fine, `DataGrid` is filled by data from Stored procedure by Data Table.
Depends on kind of data, Columns of DataGrid has different Width and I want get this Widths AFTER DataGrid is filled by data. 
Which event I have to handle to do this? I tried `DataContextChanged`, `Loaded`, `AutoGenratedColumns`, `SourceUpdated` - but all of them seems to be called before `DataGrid` is filled by data.

Any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no bulletproof way as the `DataGrid` doesn't raise any "columns generated" event but you should be able to call `Dispatcher.Invoke` with a `DispatcherPriority` lower than `DispatcherPriority.Loaded` once the `DataGrid` has been loaded, e.g.:

```
dataGrid.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
dataGrid.ItemsSource = new List<Item> { new Item() { Name = "some very long name..." } };
dataGrid.Loaded += (s, e) => 
{
    dataGrid.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
    {
        MessageBox.Show(dataGrid.Columns[0].ActualWidth.ToString());
    }), System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Input);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use several approaches to catch the moment when DataGrid's ItemsSource is changed:

1. Use DependencyPropertyDescriptor:

   ```
       DependencyPropertyDescriptor itemsSourcePropertyDescriptor = DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty(ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty, typeof(DataGrid));
       itemsSourcePropertyDescriptor.AddValueChanged(dataGrid1, OnDataGridItemsSourceChanged);

   private void OnDataGridItemsSourceChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
   }
   ```
2. Create a DataGrid descendant and override the OnItemsSourceChanged method